# Handling JSON errors still sets ModelState.IsValid to false

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, iis, json.net

My Controller accept a Json-argument as a parameter likeso:

```
[Route("status")]
[HttpPost]
public Task<JsonResult> Status([FromBody]StatusParameters parameters){}
```

Sometimes we get invalid Json sent to us and I have an Error-handler for our Json-serializer that gets called.
I set the

```
ErrorArgs.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
```

And do appropriate handling (set the nullable date to null).
Yet when The call gets into the controller and I check the

`ModelState.IsValid`
, it still contains the Json-parsing errors and returns false

Comment: You could try writing a custom model binder for your `StatusParameters` class where you could have full control over the `ModelState`.

Comment: For anyone else interesting in this question this is what I did and it solved my problem. If you post this as an answer I'd mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This process becomes a lot easier if you were to migrate to ASP.NET Core. That being said, you can create a custom model binder which gives you full access to the binding context. You can perform any validation of your DTO inside the model binder and add any ModelState errors via the binding context which can be picked up inside your controller.

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Web.Mvc;
public StatusParametersModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object GetPropertyValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor, IModelBinder propertyBinder)
    {
        if (propertyDescriptor.ComponentType != typeof(StatusParameters))
        {
            return base.GetPropertyValue(controllerContext, bindingContext, propertyDescriptor, propertyBinder);
        }

        // Get the object and validate it
        var obj = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);

        if (IsInvalid(obj))
        {
            bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError("", "");
        }

        return obj;
    }
}
```

See: [System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.defaultmodelbinder?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2).

Comment: This is how I solved it in the end for anyone else curious (though we are still using .net Framework).